# Parsing Custom Date String to MySql Date String in Java

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, simpledateformat

I have a 'Fri Jan 16 08:41:11 GMT 2015' datetime string in my database.

I would like to parse it as a mysql datetime format String.

I am trying the code below, but getting

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jan 16 08:41:11 GMT 2015".
```

Code is:

```
String date = null;
if(pos.get("utc") != null) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        Date parsed = sdf.parse("Fri Jan 16 08:41:11 GMT 2015");
        date = sdf.format(parsed);
    } catch (JSONException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at your `DateFormat` pattern. Does it match your date String?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");` [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help :-)

```
String date = null;
if(pos.get("utc") != null) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Date parsed = sdf.parse("Fri Jan 16 08:41:11 GMT 2015");
        date = sdf.format(parsed);
    } catch (JSONException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```